# Regex help! matching 5 commas

Tags: regex

```
Date,Location,Data1,Data2,Data3,$787 - $456 - $875,6.08 - 15.52,30.46,5,5,Name,LastName,42.71
Date,Location,Data1,Data2,Data3,$787 - $456 - $875,6.08 - 15.52 - 30.46,5,5,Name,LastName,42.71
```

Basically, how can I make the first line become like the second, using regex?

Is my logic right?: match 5 commas between the last $ sign and [a-z] and replace the second comma with " - "

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier (and more compatible with different languages) to use a positive lookahead to find the comma which is *followed* by 5 other commas and replace that with `-` using this regex:

```
,(?=(?:[^,]*,){5}[^,]*$)
```

In JavaScript you could do this:

```js
let str = 'Date,Location,Data1,Data2,Data3,$787 - $456 - $875,6.08 - 15.52,30.46,5,5,Name,LastName,42.71';

str = str.replace(/,(?=(?:[^,]*,){5}[^,]*$)/, ' - ');
console.log(str);
```

In PHP:

```
$str = 'Date,Location,Data1,Data2,Data3,$787 - $456 - $875,6.08 - 15.52,30.46,5,5,Name,LastName,42.71';
$str = preg_replace('/,(?=(?:[^,]*,){5}[^,]*$)/', ' - ', $str);
echo $str;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BOkb5)

In Python:

```
str = 'Date,Location,Data1,Data2,Data3,$787 - $456 - $875,6.08 - 15.52,30.46,5,5,Name,LastName,42.71';
str = re.sub(r',(?=(?:[^,]*,){5}[^,]*$)', ' - ', str);
print(str)
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/GHZD18897)

In all cases the output is:

```
Date,Location,Data1,Data2,Data3,$787 - $456 - $875,6.08 - 15.52 - 30.46,5,5,Name,LastName,42.71
```

Should your regex flavour not support lookaheads, you can replace that with a capturing group:

```
,(([^,]*,){5}[^,]*)$
```

and replace with

```
 - \1
```

[Oracle demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8142a1bb913e7862bbd9246dd628dc3f)